# Ship Longtitudinal Centre of Gravity Position

Tags: ships

This question is designed to get help from someone (with some important important questions), so that I can get an understanding on why I cannot quite get the correct answer for this question [Longtitudinal Centre of Gravity for Ship Cargo](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/35275/longtitudinal-centre-of-gravity-for-ship-cargo).

Also establishing if I have actually answered [Longtitudinal Centre of Gravity for Ship Cargo](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/35275/longtitudinal-centre-of-gravity-for-ship-cargo) question correctly and maybe the answer from the textbook is not quite correct.

---

If the Longtitudinal Centre of Gravity of a ship (without added load) is behind (aft) of it's Longtitudinal Centre of Flotation, does this affect a ships change in aft draft ?

For change in draft aft calculations, does added weight always have to be added at Longtitudinal Centre of Flotation, parallel sinkage calculated there and then change in trim calculation for movement of weight to it's actual position done from there ?

or

Can an Added weight be positioned at the ships original Longtitudinal Centre of Gravity, Parallel sinkage calculated at LCG and then the change in trim calculation for movement of weight to it's actual position done from there ?

I am thinking of a situation when it is calculated that a cargo load is to be positioned aft of the ship Longtitudinal Centre of Gravity, when the ship Longtitudinal Centre of Gravity is behind Longtitudinal Centre of Flotation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Longtitudinal Centre of Gravity for Ship Cargo](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/35275/longtitudinal-centre-of-gravity-for-ship-cargo)

Comment: @SolarMike
Hi Solar Mike, thanks very much for your reply.
The question is related to the Longtitudinal Centre of Gravity for Ship Cargo question .

The reason I have put his question up tough, is because I have tried my best in the other question to get the answer of 46.2 m , but my answer is falling short by 0. 3 m at 46.5 m.

So with this question I am trying to establish if there is something I have missed that is important.

Comment: If you are looking for responses, please provide more details, sketches, and your work.

Comment: Hi @r13

Are you a naval architect ?

I have made the question more clearer now as to how it relates to my original question which has all the details https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/35275/longtitudinal-centre-of-gravity-for-ship-cargo .

You have to realize that I have actually already attempted calculations for this questions, but my answer is not quite agreeing with the textbook.

Comment: Hi @r13

So I am writing this question to understand the concept of when a  ships centre of gravity is behind its centre of flotation does this affect it's trim.
Also how does parallel sinkage work with this situation when a load has to be positioned at a certain pint from the stern to increase the aft draft b y a certain amount (in this case 0.3 m).

Answer (score 0):

**Your first suggestion is the correct one**, so let's have a look at why.

When dealing with longitudinal stability of ships, it is crucial to be aware of the difference between the center of flotation $F$, the center of gravity $G$ and the center of buoyancy $B$.

1. The center of flotation $F$

   - is the center of gravity of the waterplane area
   - is the point about which rotation (trim) takes place, and hence where the trimming moment is taken about
   - is where the **force from extra buoyancy will attack** if weight is added to the ship (the extra buoyancy is due to the change in the vessels draft when adding weight)
   - is dependent on the geometry/curvature of the vessel, meaning that different drafts will will have different locations of the center of floatation
   - (is dependent on the trim angle, but since the trim usually is small, we tend to neglify this dependency)
2. The center of gravity $G$

   - is the longitudinal center of gravity of the vessel
   - is where the **gravitational force of the vessel will attack**
3. The center of buoyancy $B$

   - is where the **total buoyancy force of the vessel will attack**

Hence, if adding a weight to the ship, imagine it first being placed at the center of flotation, calculate the parallel sinkage, then move it to the correct location and calculate the trim angle about the **new** center of flotation (when the added mass is small, giving a small parallel sinkage, it is often sufficient to assume that the center of flotation does not change).

Consequently, it does not matter where the center of gravity is located with respect to the center of flotation, if following the procedure above.

*In the below image, $M_L$ denotes the longitudinal metacenter, which will not be further explained in this answer.*
[image: Longitudinal stability of ships]

Lastly, I will suggest those curious to dive into the appropriate literature for more details on the topic of *longitudinal stability of ships*. My suggestion includes, but is not limited to the book; *Ship Stability for Masters and Mates* by C.B. Barrass and D.R. Derrett.