# where should center of gravity of cargo for the entire structure to be JUST stable?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, civil-engineering, fluid, soil-mechanics

My work: My answer for 1 is 2.5m (floats)
For 2:

- MG must be positive and Ym - Yg must be positive
- I am not sure where to go from here.

[image: Question]

Comment: why would the pontoon be 5 m high?

Comment: The question is badly written. Yes, it needs 2.5 m of water to maintain the flotation,  yc will be the distance from the top of the platoon to the centroid of the weight, a trick question it maybe.

Comment: I would have thought it was 2 m high, and 3 m wide and a length of 5 m.

Comment: Check out [this question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/51717/ship-stability-and-overturning-moment).